# className not working on dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, classname, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I've **initial** `string` like this:-

`My first name is @John# and last name is %Smith#.`

Where I'll **replace**:-

- `@` with `<span className="contentDescHighlighted">`
- `%` with `<span className="contentDescHighlighted content_bold">`
- `#` with `</span>`

the working code is as follow:-

```js
  const handleAddingHighlight = (data) => {
    let changeAT = data.replaceAll(`@`, `<span className="contentDescHighlighted">`)
    let changePercentage = changeAT.replaceAll(`%`, `<span className="contentDescHighlighted content_bold">`)
    let highlightedData = changePercentage.replaceAll(`#`, `</span>`); console.log(highlightedData)

    return highlightedData
  }
```

After changing the `string`, then I'll **inject** them using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as follow:-

```js
  <p 
    className="contentDesc" 
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: handleAddingHighlight(`My first name is @John# and last name is %Smith#.`)}}
  ></p>
```

Unfortunately, the **styling/className** applied didn't take any effect at all as shown below:-

```js
  // what it should looks like
  <p className="contentDesc">
    My first name is <span className="contentDescHighlighted">John</span> and last name is <span className="contentDescHighlighted content_bold">Smith</span>.
  </p>
  // current outcome when using dangerouslySetInnerHTML
  <p 
    className="contentDesc" 
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: handleAddingHighlight(`My first name is @John# and last name is %Smith#.`)}}
  ></p>
```

[image]

###### Complete component will look like this

```js
export default function Test() {
  const handleAddingHighlight = (data) => {
    let changeAT = data.replaceAll(`@`, `<span className="contentDescHighlighted">`)
    let changePercentage = changeAT.replaceAll(`%`, `<span className="contentDescHighlighted content_bold">`)
    let highlightedData = changePercentage.replaceAll(`#`, `</span>`); console.log(highlightedData)

    return highlightedData
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* what it should looks like */}
      <p className="contentDesc">
        My first name is <span className="contentDescHighlighted">John</span> and last name is <span className="contentDescHighlighted content_bold">Smith</span>.
      </p>
      {/* current outcome when using dangerouslySetInnerHTML */}
      <p 
        className="contentDesc" 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: handleAddingHighlight(`My first name is @John# and last name is %Smith#.`)}}
      ></p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue. content rendered using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property must be `HTML` elements. They aren't `JSX`  at all.
It should be

```
class
```

(which is HTML attribute)

instead of

```
className
```

(which is JSX attribute)

Comment: @lala, check this out!!

Comment: Thanks man! I wouldn't have known this fact this otherwise.